# How to change icon color in UIAction inside UIMenu?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Trying to change icon color in UIAction but changing tint does not seem to work at all. Any idea?

```
let imageView = UIImage(systemName: "eye")!
                    .withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
```

The source code below is from Apple ["Adding Menus and Shortcuts to the Menu Bar and User Interface"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicommand/adding_menus_and_shortcuts_to_the_menu_bar_and_user_interface) example, only `imageView` is the new element.

```
    func contextMenuActions() -> [UIMenuElement] {
        let imageView = UIImage(systemName: "eye")?.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)

        // Actions for the contextual menu, here you apply two actions.
        let copyAction = UIAction(title: NSLocalizedString("CopyTitle", comment: ""),
                                   image: imageView,
                                   identifier: UIAction.Identifier(rawValue: "com.example.apple-samplecode.menus.copy")) { action in
                                         // Perform the "Copy" action, by copying the detail label string.
                                         if let content = self.detailItem?.description {
                                             UIPasteboard.general.string = content
                                         }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, How did you add the separator at the top of share option.

Comment: @WideAngleTechnology `Divider()`

Comment: I don't get that can you explain more?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use rendering mode `.alwaysOriginal` because internally they use `UIImageView`, which applies own `tintColor` for all template image.

So making

```
func contextMenuActions() -> [UIMenuElement] {
    let imageView = UIImage(systemName: "eye")?.withTintColor(.red, 
          renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)                            // << here !!
```

gives

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 12.1

Comment: Extra upvote for "renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal"