# Is the new "small, rounded" popup seen now in iOS (eg: weather app) available in latest UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios17

Example below,

[image]

Is this popup style now available standard in iOS? (Perhaps as one of the huge number of variations of the new 'popup style buttons'?)

I know that some people on here are clever enough to inspect apps and see what the classes are; I can't.

Is this a standard now-available interface element, or is it just custom programming?

It's a "full time job" keeping track of what's available in UIKit and I do not know the answer in this case.

Comment: Look for `UIMenuElement`, `UIMenu`, `UIAction`, etc. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenu?language=objc

Comment: The popup is available in iOS 13+, I used it on my iOS app. You do then `yourButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true; yourButton.menu = theMenu`.

Comment: Here are a few screenshot on other SO question about UIMenu & iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64714923/how-to-change-icon-color-in-uiaction-inside-uimenu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422167/does-ios-13-uimenu-have-a-bug-that-doesnt-show-its-image etc It should be exactly the class you're looking for...

Comment: On a WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10064?time=736

Comment: For questions like this you should always begin with the [Components](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components) section of the HIG. In this case it will lead you to [Pop-up buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/pop-up-buttons).

Comment: It's a great link. I'm completely familiar with standard popup buttons, I guess i was too stupid to realizer there was a way to attach a UIMenu to any old button format!

Comment: (ie the two available when you tap "+" in Xcodes interface elements UI!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Pop-Up Button made with [`UIMenu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenu?language=objc) (main starting class) and is available on iOS 13+ (since your question is about iOS).

An intro on [WWDC 21: Meet the UIKit Button System](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10064?time=736) (at ~12 minutes)

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

My confusion was I was too dumb to realize that you can (easily) use the standard popup with any button whatsoever.  *(Not just the two that are available in the standard selection in Xcode.)*

The secret is just

```
 showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
```

[image]

Create a button (or even a bar button) with any Type, Style, styling, colors etc whatsoever, say on IB.

Simply do this,

```
@IBOutlet weak var test: UIButton!
func setup() {
    test.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
```

.. and in the usual way build the menu,

```
    let hh = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Horsies", "Goldfish"]
    test.menu = UIMenu(children: hh.map({ h in
        return UIAction(title: h, image: UIImage(systemName: "eraser")) { _ in
            print("tapped \(h)")
        }
    }))
    test.forceSelectedIndex(0)
}
```

and that's it.

It may help anyone googling here.